# Square Brackets are not displaying correctly.

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I would like to put $c_{i,j}$ into stretchy square brackets [] but it keeps giving me the floor function brackets for some reason.

1. `\left[ c_{i,j} \right]` = $\left[ c_{i,j} \right]$
2. `\left\[ c_{i,j} \right\]` = $\left\[ c_{i,j} \right\]$
3. `\lbrack c_{i,j} \rbrack` = $\lbrack c_{i,j} \rbrack$
4. `\left \lbrack c_{i,j} \right \rbrack` = $\left \lbrack c_{i,j} \right \rbrack$
5. `c_{i,j}\brack` = $c_{i,j}\brack$
6. `\brack c_{i,j}` = $\brack c_{i,j}$

Option 3 seems to be it but I don't like how small it is. This is why I tried using the /left.../right tags.

It appears that other users see the correct formatting but this is what I see on my screen.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgKE.png)

Comment: Is it a fontsize issue? Your brackets appear correct to me. Please indicate your browser and operating system, and also whether you are using local fonts (right click on the math expression, select "About Mathjax" from the context menu. Tell us what it says on the top two lines.)

Comment: Browser: Chrome
OS: Windows 7
Font: MathJax.js v2.2 and TeX Input Jax v2.2.1

Comment: I don't recall `\[\]` existing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The second option was just for testing purposes because nothing was yielding the result I wanted.

Comment: In $\LaTeX$, `\[ <code>\]` does the same as double-dollars `$$ <code> $$` (so puts your maths on a line of its own).

Comment: `$\Lbrack$` and `$\Rbrack$` are just the same as `$[$` and `$]$`, in my HTML-CSS rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that when I change Math Renderer to SVG it shows my desired result. I was on HTML-CSS which gave unwanted results.

[image: Previous Setting]

[image: Correct Setting]

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what I wanted but this is good enough `$\Big[ c_{i,j} \Big]$` $\Big[ c_{i,j} \Big]$ but I can't go smaller because I get $\big[ c_{i,j} \big]$ with `$\big[ c_{i,j} \big]$`.[image: How it looks on my screen]

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hCwKX.png) is a screenshot of what I see in your answer. Seems ok to me.

Comment: @Martin That's what I want but it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/KAamjyK.png?1) on mine.

Comment: Perhaps you should include the screenshot in your question (or in your answer).

Comment: I also see floor brackets instead of square brackets in your post; same system setup as yours.

Comment: I see the floor brackets instead of square ones: Firefox 16.0.1, Vista.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see, screen-copied from your question:

[image: screen shot]

If this is not what you see, the problem is probably not with MathJax.

Comment: That's not what I see on my screen, although that is what I expected to see. If you take a look at my screenshot you'll see I end up with floor brackets. Is that my font? What settings would I need to change?