# Vector notation issue in iOS application

Tags: support, mathjax, ios-app

Everyone's answers and questions is displaying vectors very weird. For example `\vec F` gives:

$$\vec F$$

What happened? How can we fix this? I hope I don't have to redo my past answers...

[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot to show how it is displayed to *you*? Have you tried what happens if you change Math Renderer in MathJax menu?

Comment: I have added a screenshot, I don't know how to do that @MartinSleziak

Comment: This is what I see in your post here on meta: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Trrf.png

Comment: Hmm weird, perhaps it is because I am on iOS.

Comment: To see how math renderer can be changes, see the screenshots in [this answer](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/667#669) or [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10459#10471). However, I do not know whether this works on mobile devices.

Comment: If it turns out that this is problem with mobile web or Stack Exchange app, probably the relevant tags should be added - namely ([meta-tag:ios-app]) and/or ([meta-tag:mobile-web]).

Comment: Maybe it's time to switch to Android based devices.

Comment: This is due to a regression in Safari 10. The upcoming 2.7.2 release will include a workaround.

Comment: @Peter: Safari? You make it sound like it's a real jungle out there! :P

Comment: [Related question on MathOverflow's Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3207/70594).

Comment: Just thought I should add, I experience this issue on an IOS device as well.